# Notification error Could not find service with UUID on peripheral

Tags: react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to connect to an HM-10 BLE module on my React Native app. I am using [this example](https://github.com/innoveit/react-native-ble-manager/blob/master/example/App.js) but get a Notification error when connecting `Notification error Could not find service with UUID 13333333-3333-3333-3333-333333333337 on peripheral with UUID XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX` (masked my UUID with X's)

I'm not sure how to find the service UUID of my device. I open a BLE scanner app and see FFE0 for Service UUIDs but not sure what to make of it.

The code I am using is everything from https://github.com/innoveit/react-native-ble-manager/blob/master/example/App.js . I made no edits. The HM-10 BLE is part of an Arduino circuit. The scanner shows a value of 0 when a button on the circuit is unpressed and a value of 1 when the button is pressed.

I expect the console log to show a value of 1 when the button is pressed and a value of 0 when the button is unpressed.

Comment: Did you find out why?

Answer (score 2):

Did you make sure your peripheral actually includes the aforesaid service?

I recommend you use a generic tool, such as the excellent [nRF Connect](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=no.nordicsemi.android.mcp&hl=en) (also available for iOS and Windows) to connect to the peripheral, and see all of its profiles and services.